# Update Inventory system file with sales values in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, text

I am struggling to get my code in Java to do the following:

> Inventory Update program.
>
> The first set of records is the master file which reflects an item inventory at the start of the business day. Each master file record contains a part number and a corresponding item stock quantity. Let us assume that the master file contains no more than 5 records.
>
> The second set of records reflects the transactions for each of various items during that day. Transaction records contain have the same format as the master file records: they contain the item number and the corresponding total number of items sold that day. There is unknown number of such transaction records in the input file.
>
> Write a program to update the master file against the transaction file to produce the new master file at the end of the day. A record notice should accompany any item number for which fewer than 10 items remain in the stock.

The actual files look like this. (Master.txt)

```
444 40
111 30
222 15
134 20
353 5
```

And the second looks like this (Sales.txt)

```
134 03
111 29
353 02
222 10
```

And the updated version of Master.txt should look like this.

```
444 40
111 1 reorder
222 5 reorder
134 17
353 3 reorder
```

Here is my code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class inventoryUpdate {
    //Exception included due to mOrganize, sOrganize, and PrintWriter
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Scanner inKey = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Preparing the document based on how many item types were sold.
        System.out.println("How many types of products were sold?");
        int sold = inKey.nextInt();

        int[][] inMaster = fileCheck(mOrganize(), sOrganize(sold), sold);

        PrintWriter printFile = new PrintWriter("Master.txt");
        printFile.println("Item No. \tQuantity");

        for (int i = 0; i<5;i++){
            if (inMaster[i][1] < 10){
                printFile.printf("%-5s %17s You are low in inventory on this item. Please order more.\n", inMaster[i][0], inMaster[i][1]);
            }
            else{
                printFile.printf("%-5s %17s\n", inMaster[i][0], inMaster[i][1]);
            }
        }
        printFile.close();
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(inMaster));
    }

    private static int[][] mOrganize() throws Exception {
        File fileRip = new File("Master.txt");
        Scanner masterRead = new Scanner(fileRip);
        masterRead.nextLine();

        int[][] masterData = new int [5][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 2; i2++){
                masterData[i][i2] = masterRead.nextInt();
                if (masterData[i][i2] < 10){
                    masterRead.nextLine();
                }
            }
        }
        masterRead.close();
        return masterData;
    }

    private static int[][] sOrganize(int sold) throws Exception{
        File fileRip =  new File ("Sales.txt");
        Scanner saleRead = new Scanner(fileRip);
        saleRead.nextLine();

        int [][] salesData = new int [sold][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < sold; i++){
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 2; i2++){
                salesData[i][i2] = saleRead.nextInt();
            }
        }

        saleRead.close();
        return salesData;
    }

    private static int[][] fileCheck(int[][] master, int[][] sales, int sold){
        int columnBase = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            for(int i2 = 0; i2 < sold; i2++){
                if (master[i][columnBase] == sales[i2][columnBase]){
                    master[i][columnBase + 1] -= sales[i2][columnBase + 1];
                }
            }
        }
        return master;
    }
}
```

My output is as follows.

```
How many types of products were sold?
4
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at inventoryUpdate.mOrganize(inventoryUpdate.java:39)
    at inventoryUpdate.main(inventoryUpdate.java:14)
```

The code appears to break at line 14 and is related to my inMaster array.

```
int[][] inMaster = fileCheck(mOrganize(), sOrganize(sold), sold);
```

I am sure I am overlooking a syntax error of sorts, but I am failing to wrap my brain around it.

I would appreciate any help possible.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I'm sorry about that, I have edited my question accordingly. Thank you for the help.

Comment: When reading files you are reading both a whole line and int by int, chose one or another but do not use both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably a lack of making your methods too specific, and you expect too much precision in the input.

In `mOrganize`, you are explicitly reading away the new lines. However, the last line doesn't contain any newline, so it fails.

To be perfectly honest, `nextInt` happily skips whitespace, so none of the `nextLine` statements are necessary *at all* and your code runs if you remove them.

---

`mOrganize` should just be called `organize` if you follow Java naming conventions, and just `readInventory` with a `File` parameter if you want to let it make any sense.

---

I'm not sure how much you've learned about programming, but things like 5 and 10 in `mOrganize` are called *magic values* and should be avoided. What you really want is to create a class e.g. `ItemInventory` and `ItemSales`, make a Java `List` out of those and then read the files until the end. That way your code will work even if there are more or fewer lines in the files.

Here is a bit more advanced example that uses a `Map` rather than a `List`:

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> readInventory(File file) throws IOException {
    var inventory = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    try (var lineScanner = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (lineScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            // we assume each item is on it's own line
            var line = lineScanner.nextLine();
            try (var itemScanner = new Scanner(line)) {
                var no = itemScanner.nextInt();
                var amount = itemScanner.nextInt();
                if (inventory.put(no, amount) != null) {
                    // a more specific exception such as InventoryException might be better
                    throw new RuntimeException("Duplicate item in inventory file");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return inventory;
}
```

an item number is unique after all, and you would not expect it twice in the same inventory.

As you can see, it would be easy to put more information in the same line now, although that would mean changing the return value to something other than `Map<Integer, Integer>` - for instance `Map<Item, Integer>` if you define a new `Item` class.

It is now completely independent of the amount of items in the file, no magic numbers anymore. It also is able to read from any file, rather than just `Master.txt`.

---

I hope it is abundantly obvious that rewriting "Master.txt" won't help you with debugging, as you need to restore it each time you run the code.

Comment: Thank you *so* much. This helped immensely. I didn't know the Map concept, but it is invaluable. I appreciate your in-depth response